# Output elements between specific element

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I have a table with a column which looks like:

```
SELECT Col1 
FROM table;


Col1
A
A
B
B
C
C
D
B
E
B
F
```

I would like to output elements that are between "B"s, which are C, D, E
How can I do that with a query?

Comment: Short answer, you can't. If you have nothing to order by, there _is_ no "between two rows", since the order you're getting is pseudo random. If you add an ORDER BY to your query, it's doable.

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @t table (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),col1 VARCHAR(10))
insert into @t (col1) values ('A')
insert into @t (col1) values ('A')
insert into @t (col1) values ('B')
insert into @t (col1) values ('B')
insert into @t (col1) values ('C')
insert into @t (col1) values ('C')
insert into @t (col1) values ('B')
insert into @t (col1) values ('E')
insert into @t (col1) values ('B')
insert into @t (col1) values ('F')

select ID,col1 from @t
where ID between (select MIN(id) from @t WHERE col1 = 'B') and 
(select MAX(id) from @t WHERE col1 = 'B')
and col1<>'B'
```